# Adding new year i new column in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm newbie in MySQL and I have a table which has columns

```
+---------------------+-------------+
|        Date         | Temperature |
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 10,1        |
| 2016-01-02 00:00:00 | 10,2        |
| ...                 | ...         |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 12,1        |
| 2017-01-02 00:00:00 | 12,5        |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

I would like receive the result

```
+--------+------+------+
|  Date  | 2016 | 2017 |
+--------+------+------+
| 01 Jan | 10,1 | 12,1 |
| 02 Jan | 10,2 | 12,5 |
| ...    | ...  | ...  |
+--------+------+------+
```

I wanted to use subquery, but subquery can have 1 row. Someone could help me write the correct query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use CASE statement

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(samay, '%e %b') AS date_month,  
MAX(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM samay) = 2016  THEN temp END) AS '2016', 
MAX(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM samay) = 2017 THEN temp END) AS '2017' 
FROM date_test GROUP BY date_month;
```

Comment: You'll need to use a `MAX()` function to aggregate those `CASE` expressions.  Otherwise, this is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @BaconBits I consider single row for each day

Comment: This is not exactly what i wanted. In result from this query i receive three columns: date, 2016, 2017. In the column "date" is displayed all the dates (from 2016 and 2017 year). In rows with date from 2016 first column have correct value (from 2016 year), second column have null values. In rows with date from 2017 first column have null value, second column have values from 2017 year.

Comment: @Robson I update above code so use it, it will give correct result as you want.

Comment: Now its working perfectly. This method is simpler and easier to understand for me. Thanks!
It is possible to automatically add new column, when new year (e.g 2018) come? I mean dynamically adding column in MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
select d.fdate, t1.t, t2.t
from
(select distinct month(d) as month, day(d) as day, DATE_FORMAT(d, '%e %b') as fdate from h) as d
left outer join
(select DATE_FORMAT(d, '%e %b') as fdate, t from h where year(`d`) = 2016) as t1 on (d.fdate = t1.fdate)
left outer join
(select DATE_FORMAT(d, '%e %b') as fdate, t from h where year(`d`) = 2017) as t2 on (d.fdate = t2.fdate)
order by d.month, d.day
```

of course change column/table names

Demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/920ea2/2

Comment: Thanks! This work fine for me, but result is sorting alphabetically by day and month e.g 1 April, 1 August, 1 december... and next 10 april, 10 august, 10 december.

Comment: @Robson I've updated answer to show how you can sort result

Comment: Thanks! You are great!